# Handling Mutual TLS verification with ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, mtls

This is how my server app `Program.cs` looks:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(kestelOptions =>
{
    kestelOptions.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(httpOptions =>
    {
        httpOptions.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.AllowCertificate;
    });
});

var services = builder.Services;

services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCertificate(options =>
    {
        options.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.All;
        options.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online;
    });

services.AddInfrastructureServices(builder.Configuration);
services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

I have to authenticate multiple clients with mTLS and I store their verified certificates thumbprints and serials in database. But how to verify that the request that contains certificate is valid? I mean that everyone can get website certificate, so comparison thumbprint and serial from db with sent certificate isn't enough.

But how to verify it? I don't have any idea.

Comment: Because "everyone can get website public key certificate",  if Certificates are only owned by some people, then is certificate enough?

Comment: I think certificate isn't enough, because as I mentioned everyone can get website certificate.

Comment: Ok, as you mentioned everyone can get website certificate, certificate isn't enough. Do you want to determine a user's identity or whether a user has access to a resource ?

Comment: I want to determine OAuth client identity.